# Import Excel data into SQL 2008 without subtotal and totals with Sql Server Studio

Tags: sql, excel-2007

I want to import an excel 2007 data without sub totals and totals using Sql Server Studio.   I tried importing directly but comes along with the sub totals and totals too.  Is there a straight forward way in doing this?

Or is there an alternative way of doing this import?

**Edit 1 Added excel format**

I am not using any query just using sql wizard to import.  Just trying to do it without any scripts.

Excel format

```
ProgramID | Name   |  Amount
20        | Adrian |     20
20        | Jack   |     35
           Sub Total     55  <== This I do not want to import
21        | Janet  |     25
21        | Jill   |     20
           Sub Total     45  <== This I do not want to import

           Total        100  <== This I do not want to import
```

Comment: please provide an example of the table you are importing and also the query you are using to import. I think the only way will be to filter out the rows that are totals.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `OPENROWSET` then you can simply add a where clause to the query

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=path\to\the.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [sheet_name$] WHERE NAME NOT LIKE ''%Total%'' AND NAME <> ''''')
```

If you need to set up the providers etc. I recommend reading [this](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries.htm) which also provides examples and alternative methods for importing data from Excel.

Using Tasks -> Import Data; after setting up source and destination, select "write a query..." then use a similar query as above such as

```
SELECT * FROM `sheet_name$` WHERE `Name` NOT LIKE "%Total%" AND Name <> ""
```

For some reason using a query messes up the data type mappings [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/97ff1f01-c02a-4c9a-b867-8eaecc464cfb/2012-sp1-no-longer-recognizes-common-data-types). So based on the link I added

```
<!-- VarChar Query Kludge -->
<dtm:DataTypeMapping >
    <dtm:SourceDataType>
        <dtm:DataTypeName>200</dtm:DataTypeName>
    </dtm:SourceDataType>
    <dtm:DestinationDataType>
        <dtm:CharacterStringType>
            <dtm:DataTypeName>DT_STR</dtm:DataTypeName>
            <dtm:UseSourceLength/>
        </dtm:CharacterStringType>
    </dtm:DestinationDataType>
</dtm:DataTypeMapping>

<!-- NVarChar Query Kludge -->
<dtm:DataTypeMapping >
    <dtm:SourceDataType>
        <dtm:DataTypeName>202</dtm:DataTypeName>
    </dtm:SourceDataType>
    <dtm:DestinationDataType>
        <dtm:CharacterStringType>
            <dtm:DataTypeName>DT_WSTR</dtm:DataTypeName>
            <dtm:UseSourceLength/>
        </dtm:CharacterStringType>
    </dtm:DestinationDataType>
</dtm:DataTypeMapping>
```

To `AceToSSIS.xml` which seemed to 'resolve' the issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand everything of this will try when I get some time and update here